# c, can't print characters from a string

Tags: c

i'm trying to create a delay print function (print a character of a string every second).

my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

void delayPrint(char* s);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    delayPrint("ciao");
    return 0;
}

void delayPrint(char* s)
{
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        Sleep(1);
        printf("%s", s[i]);
    }
}
```

I can't print a specific character of a string: i can print the entire string in the displayPrint function.
Now the function simply does nothing.

I can't understand the problem (Windows 11, mingw)
Anyone can help?

Comment: Replace `%s` with `%c`.

Comment: Change `for (int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)` to `for (int i=0; s[i]; i++)` to increase performance#

Comment: And add `flush(stdout)` after the (corrected) `printf("%c", s[i]);`

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you be using %c to print the character??

```
printf("%c", s[i]);
```

instead of:

```
 printf("%s", s[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that your code has `Sleep(1)`. This function takes milliseconds. So it is probably faster than you wanted. For one second you should change it to `Sleep(1000)`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep

Answer (score 1):

You are providing `%s` as an argument to `printf` but your are giving it a character `s[i]`. `printf` expects `%s` to be a pointer to a null-terminated string (which means there should be a `\0` character at the end of the string to detect that it ended).

```
for (int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        Sleep(1);
        printf("%s", s[i]);
    }
```

You should change `%s` to `%c`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you made an error in your placeholder.
You should change your %s to %c to print  char.